# Error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have both VS 2005 and 2008 installed on my machine. 2005 is fine.  For 2008, literally any asp.net project I try to create gets this eror.  I try stepping into the code, and the error occurs apparently before anything that I can trap is loaded.  There is no information written to the event log.

I have tried this with a "Hello World" webpage with nothing else going on.  Seems unique to my Windows Server 2003 machine.

TIA for help.

Comment: I've received this error when going to the .net 3.5 framework from a 2.0 web app and I have a reference in my web app to the Office Interop library.  Not sure if this is your case or not.

Comment: are you sure that is not hardware error ? Maybe if you clear your machine, open it close it clear the contacts of the memory ?

Comment: To add some hopefully relevant information: the error occurs only when I'm debugging using the development server.  If I set it to use IIS, it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something went wrong with your installation. Why don't you try to reinstall VS or at least run aspnet_regiis to remove & re-add the framework.